# Saturday chat critique

Tags: discussion

We've been getting a lot of people discussing, myself included, about critiques whether from site designs, logo, etc. etc if they would be allowed in GD.

I'm thinking maybe a set time on Saturday August 24 and we could focus on three areas, logo, icon, and web.  I think we can possibly create a meta post titled discussion and let people answer with their critique questions (I need advise on this and that with picture added).  It can be voted by the powers (Yisela & John) which ones will be discussed that weekend.  Also, limit the questions by monthly to allow others a chance.

This has been moved [here](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/654/critique-week-starting-this-saturday).

Comment: Good idea. I'll watch but probably not participate. I tend to ruffle too many feathers during critiques.

Comment: you should participate because some consider you as a GD role model

Comment: then... the end is NIGH!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 7):

I think it's an excellent idea! We can even extend it to **Brainstorming Saturday**, sort of a weekly chat even where you can bring your design and we all try to break it to pieces :D

We can create **scheduled events** for this, so the regular users get notified and the rest can see it in the site ticker box.